# Mover formas con el mouse

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando un pequeño programa en el que dibujo diferentes formas en un panel (rectángulos,elipses,regiones,etc...). Necesito poder mover esas formas pero no se me ocurre ninguna manera de "seleccionarlas" para poder arrastrarlas por el panel a mi antojo. 
He conseguido mover todo el entorno con translatetransform pero quiero mover solo la forma que dibuje (el fondo tendrá un mallado).
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo

```
        internal void Pintar_en_panel(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;           
            int x=0, y=0;
            //Hay que tener hacer el cambio de unidades para no perder la proporcion entre figuras
            float clicx, clicy, trasx, trasy;            
            int.TryParse(txtX1.Text,out x);
            int.TryParse(txtY1.Text,out y);      

            if (escalado==true){g.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);}



                //Vemos el desplazamiento entre coordenadas del mouse cuando se inicia el arrastre
                clicx = xf - x0;
                clicy = yf - y0;

                if (clicx > 0 || clicy > 0)
                {
                    g.TranslateTransform(clicx, clicy);

                }
**//Aqui es donde se crea el rectangulo en el panel 1,las condiciones se cumplen en un panel2**             

            if (condiciones == true)//Si se cumple el doble click se dibuja el cuadrado en el panel1
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.DeepSkyBlue, 100, 100, 300, 300);
            }


            g.Dispose();

        }
```

```
     private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Obtenemos las coordenadas del mouse cuando se presiona el raton
            x0 = e.X;
            y0 = e.Y;            
            clicking = true; //mientras se presione clicking se cumple



        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Obtenemos las coordenadas del mouse cuando se suelta el raton
            xf = e.X;
            yf = e.Y;


            clicking = false;//Cuando se suelta clicking se vuelve falso

        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {


            if (clicking==true)//Solo entra si estamos manteniendo el click
            {   xf = e.X;
                yf = e.Y;                
                Refresh();}}
```

Comment: Que has intentado ??? sube el codigo que llevas hasta ahora.

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO No sé si me falta alguna cosa para que sea entendible...

Comment: No se si catalogar la pregunta como _demasiado amplia_. Si hablamos de windows forms, el tema es complejo dado que una vez has dibujado una forma, deja de ser una forma y es simplemente un conjunto de pixels a dibujar. Hacer lo que pides requeriría almacenar en algun sitio los parametros de creación de una forma (tipo, posicion, tamaño...), detectar manualmente cuando pinches en una forma y gestionar el movimiento de la misma manualmente. Como digo, tiene su complejidad y creo que explicarlo sería muy extenso para el formato del sitio.

Comment: @Pikoh Tan solo pido algo de orientación. No espero que se me escriba todo el código. Pero si puedes ayudarme con los pasos que debería seguir sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: @Tormund los pasos básicos ya te los he explicado en mi anterior comentario. Cada vez que crees una "forma", deberías almacenar en alguna estructura su información, para posteriormente detectar manualmente cuando pinches en una forma y gestionar el movimiento de la misma manualmente.

Comment: en windows forms, esto es casi (digo casi) imposible. Es un lio porque tenes que armar controles transparentes para saber donde esta apretando y tener una estructura de datos que sepa si esta aprentando en un pixel que tiene algo o no. en wpf es un "poco" mas simple...

Comment: @gbianchi Pues a por el casi imposible! :)

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias, intentaré ir por ahi...

Comment: Intenta lo que te he dicho y si en alguna de las partes te estancas o tienes algun problema, una pregunta específica sobre cualquiera de las partes probablemente este mas dentro de tematica del sitio y trataremos de ayudarte de una manera mas concreta.  Un saludo :)

Comment: Echa un vistazo tambien a [este articulo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146648/Controlling-Drawn-Shapes-in-C) que podría ayudarte